# Hardhat and Chai testing : How should I write the test?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, chai

I've digged through all the related question, but none of these worked for me.
I used this repo, and replaced the contract and test file : https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat-boilerplate

**EDIT 26/11** : was able to reproduce it with a simple modification from the repo above, if you want to try it yourself :
https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat-boilerplate/issues/79

I'll start by giving the context of the issue, then I'll present my issue.

**Context description**

the contract is a multi-sig wallet with approvers defined at construction.
I get signers here, and then deploy my contract where I set signer0..2 as approvers :

```
const [signer0, signer1, signer2, signer3, signer4] = await ethers.getSigners();
const wallet = await walletFactory.deploy([signer0.address, signer1.address, signer2.address]);
```

I'm testing this solidity function :

```
    function createTransfer (uint amount, address payable to) external onlyApprover() {
    transfers.push(Transfer(
        transfers.length,
        amount,
        to,
        0,
        false)
    );
}
```

which has a modifier onlyApprover :

```
    modifier onlyApprover() {
    bool allowed = false;
    for (uint i=0; i<approvers.length; i++) {
        if (approvers[i] == msg.sender) {
            allowed = true;
        }
    }
    require(allowed == true, "only approver allowed");
    _;
}
```

When calling this function with an account which is not part of the approvers array, it reverts.

**Issue**

```
 await expect(wallet.connect(signer3).createTransfer(100, addr4, {from: signer3.address}));
```

OR

```
await expect(wallet.connect(signer3).createTransfer(100, addr4, {from: signer3.address})
    ).to.be.reverted;
```

The test pass while it should pass only for the second one

If I put the await inside the expect :

```
 expect(await wallet.connect(signer3).createTransfer(100, addr4, {from: signer3.address}));
```

OR

```
expect(await wallet.connect(signer3).createTransfer(100, addr4, {from: signer3.address})
    ).to.be.reverted;
```

The test do not pass in both cases with this error, which is the solidity error I expect !.. but it should be caught by the test and validate it in the to.be.reverted case.

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'only approver allowed'

I also tried using to.be.revertedWith('only approver allowed'), same issue in both case.

**questions**

What am I missing ?
Does someone have a repo to share where I could see something like that implemented and working ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from a member of this repo which explain everything :

*If you do await expect(...something...), the promise returned inside the expect will be captured by Chai. **If you then don't assert anything on that promise, then the result will be discarded and the test will pass**.*

I wasn't aware of that, now I found how to verify that a transaction is NOT reverted (what I was looking for), I need to use `.not.to.be.reverted` : https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_not